# @ECHO OFF not working to OFF the echo messages of ANT targets calling from java, which inturn is being called from batch

Tags: java, ant, batch-file, echo

I'm calling java (.jar) from batch. These java inturn calls ANT targets, where there are some echo messages. I've used @echo off in the first line of my batch file. But still The messages of echo (from ant targets) are getting printed.

Please help me to make the echo completely disabled.

Thanks,
Chandra

My batch file contents:

```
@echo off

SET HOME="%CD%"
SET CLASSPATH=%HOME%
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%HOME%\lib\ant\activation.jar;%HOME%\lib\ant\ant.jar;%HOME%\lib\ant\ant-launcher.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%HOME%\lib\ant-ext\ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar;%HOME%\lib\ant-ext\antcount.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%HOME%\lib\utilities.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%HOME%\lib\AbsoluteLayout.jar;
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%HOME%\dist\TestGUI.jar;

java -cp %CLASSPATH% TestGUI %HOME%
```

Comment: The `echo off` command has absolutely nothing to do with the messages that go to the terminal from the invoked programs. It exclusively turns off the display of the command lines (the lines in the BAT file) as they are executed in the BAT file.

Comment: Maybe `-quiet -silent`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@echo off` doesn't have to do anything with Ant's `<echo/>`.

Perhaps you could try with `ant -f yourbuildfile.xml -quiet` or just `ant -quiet` if your build file is called `build.xml`.

Comment: where I need to call this ant -quiet, In Java or in batch?

Comment: In your batch script, wherever you make the `ant` call. Show me your batch script if you don't understand.

Comment: @echo off

SET HOME="%CD%"
SET CLASSPATH=%HOME%
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%HOME%\lib\ant\activation.jar;%HOME%\lib\ant\ant.jar;%HOME%\lib\ant\ant-launcher.jar
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%HOME%\lib\ant-ext\ant-contrib-1.0b3.jar;%HOME%\lib\ant-ext\antcount.jar

SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%HOME%\lib\AbsoluteLayout.jar;
SET CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;%HOME%\dist\UpgradeUtilityGUI.jar;

java -cp %CLASSPATH% UpgradeUtilityGUI %HOME%

Comment: Can you edit your question and paste it there? I can hardly understand what you've typed in the comment.

Comment: I'm calling ant target inside java program using AntUtils.executeAntTarget(<xmlfile>, <properties file>,
<ant target name>);

Comment: Why are you doing this way? You could directly call the ant command with `ant -f build.xml -quiet compile` inside the batch file. Here `compile` will be your target.

Comment: Actually some of the functionalality is present in existing ant targets, so we are directly calling them in java whenever we require that funcationality in a logical (conditional) way...